# Sails.js policies not working when controller in folder

Tags: sails.js, policies

after a bit of time, I found why my policies were not working.

I have the following file tree:

> myProject > api > controllers > v1 > UserController

When i was applying my policy to UserController, nothing would change:

```
UserController: {
    '*': 'sessionAuth',
}
```

I then tried moved the UserController under controllers :

> myProject > api > controllers > UserController

This worked.

So my questions is the following, can I still have the v1 folder and have policies working? I want to be able to have version folder.
The suggestion made here is not really great, prepending all your controller with a version number is a bit redundant to me. [Nested Models and controllers in sails are not working Policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367549/nested-models-and-controllers-in-sails-are-not-working-policies)

Looking forward to hear your thoughts!

Thanks

Comment: After looking into it, it seems the only way to do this (sails.js v0.11) is to prepend or append a version number to your controller (eg V1UserController). A dedicated folder will cause issues with policies so this is the best option as far as I know. Not the neatest but will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

'v1/userController':{
   "*":true
}

Comment: This worked for me in Sails v1. Should be marked as the correct answer.